# Database First - trying to recreate my entities that exist

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I'm trying to connect my app to an existing Application.
So i created the Entities with the Entity Framework Database First.

It create all my entities and my Context that's fine.
But when i try to run it tell me that my migrations are not up-to-date so i tried to add-migration test to see what was missing...

It's creating all the table i asked it from DataBase First...

I cant recreate those tables i just want to be able to connect to those tables...

I absolutly need to connect to those tables, i cannot create a new one and i cannot clone the database.

How can i achieve this... i didnt find any resources on the subject that goes from the start to the end of the process.

Some help would be awesome!

Comment: Delete edmx file and create new one. It work fine

Comment: I try to use the Code First From DataBase. Because i will add entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem: You can't reset migrations with existing tables in the database as EF wants to create the tables from scratch.

What to do:

Delete existing migrations from Migrations_History table.

Delete existing migrations from the Migrations Folder.

Run add-migration Reset. This will create a migration in your Migration folder that includes creating the tables (but it will not run it so it will not error out.)

You now need to create the initial row in the MigrationHistory table so EF has a snapshot of the current state. EF will do this if you apply a migration. However, you can't apply the migration that you just made as the tables already exist in your database. So go into the Migration and comment out all the code inside the "Up" method.

Now run update-database. It will apply the Migration (while not actually changing the database) and create a snapshot row in MigrationHistory.

You have now reset your migrations and may continue with normal migrations.

Comment: It seem's to work as i want! i just need to fixe a probleme with Dynamic Filter in the App and i will mark this as a Correct Answer!

Comment: Dynamic Filter are a pain in the ass.... it still doesn't work because it remove all the filter in the database... and i need to keep them.

Comment: There is a real problem with this approach if you have dynamic filter... i deleted entities and IDBSet from my Context and created a simple entitiy and added his IDBSet and created a migration and it work but if i do the Database first approach it break something ...

Comment: Nvm, it was an entitiy that was so badly designed that Entity Framework was destroying a lot of thing in the entities.... i dont know why he was trying to destroy Dynamic filter on entities that was not even touched by the Database first lol but now it work thx a lot for your help :)